# how ifstream init massive of strings

Tags: c++

Im beginner in C++
I have code:

```
    std::ifstream inFile(makeFolder/"file");
    std::string str[3];
    while(!inFile.eof())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
            inFile >> str[i];
    }

        
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            std::cout << str[i];
```

and text file with:

```
123\n
456\n
789\n
```

When I execute this program I have out to console:

```
123
456
789
```

But if I change `i`  to 2 in cycle where I init `str` I have this out:

```
789
456
```

And if I change `i`  to 1 in cycle where I init `str` I have this out:

```
789
```

Why I have this out? I must be see out if I input `i=1` 123 and if `i=2`456.

Comment: You may want to read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/11082165)

Comment: Your code snippet is confusing, why do you need a for loop inside the while loop? Just make a vector of strings: `while (inFile >> tempString) vec_of_strings.push_back(tempString);`

Comment: also you only initialize the first value of your `str` (which is an array of `std::string`, and then you're reading the whole array,... something is going wrong with your outputs